# Is there a way to wrap a jquery function to an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, oop, scope

Is there anyway to limit the scope of a jquery function to an object other than using a main function:

```
(function( $ ) {

    $.fn.myLib = function( funcName ) {

        if ( action === "func1") {
            // Open popup code.
        }

        if ( action === "func2" ) {
            // Close popup code.
        }

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

I'd like to do it so that I could call functions like this:

```
$(el).myLib.func1();
$(el).myLib.func2();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's really not a lot of good reason to try to do this:

```
$(el).myLib.func1();
```

Because the `this` pointer when `func1()` executes will be `myLib` and you won't be able to access `$(el)`.  So, it doesn't do you a whole lot of good unless all you want is static methods.  If that's what you actually want, then you can do this:

```
$.fn.myLib = {};
$.fn.myLib.func1 = function(...) {...};
$.fn.myLib.func2 = function(...) {...};
```

If you actually want to be able to have acceess to the jQuery object (which I presume), then stick to one level and use a name prefix which gives you about the same level of name conflict protection anyway.

```
$.fn.myLibFunc1 = function(...) {...};
$.fn.myLibFunc2 = function(...) {...};
```

Then, you can do:

```
$(el).myLibFunc1();
```

And, the `this` pointer in myLibFunc1 will be the jQuery object that called it.

Comment: Yuup that's what I was aiming for (still being able to access 'this'). I'll stick to the alternative (mylibFunc1();)

Answer (score 0):

```
(function( $ ) {
$.fn.myLib = function( funcName ) {
   var obj=new Object
   obj.func1=function () {alert('first')}
   obj.func2=function () {alert('second')}
   return obj

};
}( jQuery ));
```